# Force writing only-read register #Modbus

Tags: modbus, scada

I was wondering,
Is there anyway to force writing on a 'Read-Only' Modbus Register?
Does defining a Register as a 'Read-Only' is secure enough or can be bypassed??

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: I don't know but ... Also keep in mind that the registers sometimes use different addressing for reading vs the address for writing. (e.g. with WAGO 750 devices)

Comment: Hey, I face devices which holds some registers as only r, and some as r/w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to define a "read-only" analog variable in Modbus is to map it as an input register. There is no function code defined in Modbus to write to an input register.

For historical reasons, several vendors maps all their variables as holding registers, which are theoretically read/write, i.e, there's a Write Multiple Registers function. Whenever they map a read only variable as a holding register, they must assert that the write functions fail. However, there's no standard exception code for this, as a holding register should be read/write. This is only one of Modbus' idiosyncrasies.

Getting back to your question, if you map your variable as an input register, you can be sure that the protocol will not allow a master to write to it. If, for interoperability issues you map it as a holding register, the protocol will allow the master to use a write funcion to change its value, and it is up to you to block in your device implementation.